# Stuck in displaying values in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm writing a dictionary code that asks that user to input how many keys and values they want to create, but the problem is that I managed to find a way to take the user input but now somehow I'm stuck at displaying the dictionary.

Here is my dictionary code

```
dictionary = {}

keys = int(input("How many keys u want? "))

value = int(input("How many values u want?"))

for i in range(keys):
    k = input("Key: ")
    for j in range(value):
        v = input("Value: ")
        dictionary[k] = v

 print(dictionary)
```

so when I run the code the program it give me the following result which displays only 1 value even though I entered 2 values.

[image: Output]

But I want a output where it displays every value I entered for example like this

```
{ "Name" : ["David","Adam"],"Address" : ["101 street","102 street"] }
```

Comment: On each iteration when you insert value to the key, you actually replace the value inserted before. To fix it, create each value as a list, and append to it on each iteration, and when all iterations done - insert it to the key.

Comment: To go along with @YossiLevi 's comment, most people would use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` for this to simplify the code for adding the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will post it also as an answer so that you will have the code properly, with no need to
struggle with it:

```
dictionary = {}

keys = int(input("How many keys u want? "))

value = int(input("How many values u want?"))

for i in range(keys):
    k = input("Key: ")
    values = []
    for j in range(value):
        v = input("Value: ")
        values.append(v)
    dictionary[k] = values

print(dictionary)
```

output:

```
How many keys u want? 2
How many values u want?2
Key: a
Value: 1
Value: 2
Key: b
Value: 3
Value: 4
{'a': ['1', '2'], 'b': ['3', '4']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corresponding code to what @Yossi Levi said:

```
dictionary = {}

keys = int(input("How many keys u want? "))

value = int(input("How many values u want?"))


for i in range(keys):
    k = input("Key: ")
    val_list = []
    for j in range(value):
        v = input("Value: ")
        val_list.append(v)
    dictionary[k] = val_list

print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

In looking at what you're trying to do and seeing some of the comments added to your question, looks like this would work for your use case:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint as pp

dictionary = defaultdict(list) # so every key maps to a list

keys = 2
values = 2

for i in range(keys):
    k = input("Key: ")
    for j in range(value):
        v = input("Value: ")
        dictionary[k].append(v)

pp(dictionary)
```